# How to get all the time strings in a textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Here's the text. I want to get all the specific time and insert it on a listbox

```
7:00-8:00/9:00-10:00/3:00-4:00
```

How can I get all the text that has a time format like this `#:##` or `##:##`. It should output inside the listbox like this:

```
7:00
8:00
9:00
10:00
3:00
4:00
```

Comment: Uppercase text means [SHOUTING](http://jaysondbradley.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/angry.jpg) at us

Comment: Oh sorry my friend. I'm just stressed out and forgot the rules in life and my manners. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Dim s As String = "7:00-8:00/9:00-10:00/3:00-4:00"
s = s.Replace("/"C, "-"C)
Dim array As String() = s.Split("-"C)
For Each items In array 
    //add this items to list control
Next
```

Now you have Array of string you just need to iterate this array and add this array elements to list control

Comment: No need for the square brackets round `String`

Comment: @MattWilko Thanks Update Ans

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sir, how can I put the splitted strings inside the listbox? TYIA

Comment: You just need to iterate array and add its element to listbox

Comment: No need for the `Replace` step, just `s.Split("-"c, "/"c)`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
 Dim list As String = "7:00-8:00/9:00-10:00/3:00-4:00"
 Dim formatList As String() = list.Replace("-", "/").Split("/"c)

 For Each element In formatList
     MessageBox.Show(element) 'here you should add them to the list
 Next
```

Comment: Split accepts a single char as one of the overloads. You should use that instead of a char array with a single element i.e. `Split("/"c)`

Comment: Doesn't work as desired(if i've understood the requirement) if the timespan is greater than one hour. I think that then all hours between should be listed.

Comment: Thank you sir you save my life :)

Comment: Just one question sir. How can I split days like in this format: 
M/W/TH

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think that from the output example he just want to separe each hour

Comment: @WeaponX: maybe, then [i've overcomplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36428051/284240) it unnecessarily ;)

Answer (score 0):

You want to list all hours between two timespans?

You could use string methods to extract the `TimeSpan` objects and a `HashSet(Of TimeSpan)` to collect them. Use `TimeSpan` methods to parse it and to extract all between start and end:

```
Dim text = "7:00-8:00/9:00-10:00/3:00-4:00"
Dim tsStart As TimeSpan
Dim tsEnd As TimeSpan
Dim timespans = From token In text.Split("/"c)
                Select startEnd = token.Split("-"c)
                Where startEnd.Length = 2 _
                    AndAlso TimeSpan.TryParse(startEnd(0), tsStart) _
                    AndAlso TimeSpan.TryParse(startEnd(1), tsEnd)
                Select New With {.Start = tsStart, .End = tsEnd}

Dim timeSet As New HashSet(Of TimeSpan)
For Each span In timespans
    Dim between = span.End - span.Start
    For h As Int32 = 0 To between.Hours
        timeSet.Add(span.Start.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(h)))
    Next
Next

For Each ts In timeSet
    listBox.Items.Add(ts.ToString())
Next
```

This also validates the input and enables to order by `TimeSpan` instead of insertion if desired. Replace the `HashSet(Of T)` with a `List(Of T)` if duplicates should be allowed.